# Overwrite the click bind at run time when clicking other div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am planning to overwrite some of the functionality at run time. So what I am trying is to unbind first and bind again. This is working, but I am want to know how it is working. For example I did as below. Is this correct way to overwrite at run time if I want to?

```
$('#test').bind('click', function (event) {
    alert("hello");
});  

$('#test2').bind('click', function (event) {

    alert("test again");

    $('#test').unbind();

    $('#test').bind('click', function (event) {
        alert("hey test");
    });
});
```

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g6dd5q1/)**

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct way, but you should use jQuery `on/off` for attach/detach event handlers. From jQuery Documentation (http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    alert('hello');
});  

$('#test2').on('click', function() {
    alert('test again');

    $('#test').off('click');
    $('#test').on('click', function() {
        alert('hey test');
    });      
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/rqqzvwak/3/

Answer (score 0):

> In the simplest case, with no arguments, `.unbind()` removes all
>   handlers attached to the elements

Your code can be improved just to be less error prone by following the pattern below:

```
var testClicked = function (event) {
    alert("hello");
};
var neverSayDie = function(event){
    alert("'hello' is gone, but I'm still here!");
};

$('#test').bind('click', testClicked);
$('#test').bind('click', neverSayDie);

$('#test2').bind('click', function (event) {

    alert("test again");

    // only the click event registered to be handled
    // by testClick function will be unregistered 
    $('#test').unbind("click", testClicked);

    $('#test').bind('click', function (event) {
        alert("hey govind");
    });
});
```

Here's your [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/8g6dd5q1/1/).

Whether to use *bind/unbind* or *on/off*, is a completely different question. JQuery **recommends** *on/off*, but if *bind/unbind* pleases you more, hey, enjoy!